# Chamar senha do Projeto Vba

Tags: vba

Olá, preciso executar uma macro que é a `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave`porem a planilha aponta que o projeto está protegido e por isso não executa.

Queria saber como posso chamar a caixa da senha, para poder destravar e travar rapidamente.

O código que estou tentando usar:

```
    Sub ProtectVBProject()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Ativa a planilha a ser bloqueada
    wb.Activate

    ' Envia o comando para abrir o VBA
    SendKeys "%{F11}", True

    ' Abre a janela de proteção do projeto VBA
    wb.VBProject.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=761, recursive:=True).Execute ' Aqui eu precisaria do ID da caixa da senha

End Sub
```

Se possível gostaria de uma luz. Tentei pesquisar os ID's possíveis, não encontrei nenhum compatível.

Comment: Porque está chamando esse ID `761`? Ele não é a janela de proteção do projeto, é o ID `2578` que é o que chama as propriedades do projeto.

Comment: `Queria saber qual é o numero do hahaha` hein?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma maneira de buscar os `ID's` que podem ser utilizados nesse método `FindControl`, seria algo assim:

```
Private Sub ListarIDs()
    Dim ctrl1 As CommandBarControl, ctrl2 As CommandBarControl

    ' Percorre os primeiros níveis da barra de menu do VBA: Arquivo, Editar, Exibir, Inserir, Formatar, Depurar...
    For Each ctrl1 In Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls
        ' Exibe o nome e o ID do primeiro nível
        Debug.Print "Nome: " & ctrl1.Caption & " - ID: " & ctrl1.ID
        ' Percorre os submenus como Arquivo > Salvar, Depurar > Compilar VBAProject...
        For Each ctrl2 In Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(ctrl1.Caption).Controls
            ' Exibe o nome e o ID do segundo nível
            Debug.Print "Nome: " & ctrl2.Caption & " - ID: " & ctrl2.ID
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

O `ID` que você precisa pra fazer isso é o `2578` que se refere as propriedades do projeto, que é onde você pode usar o `SendKeys` pra proteger e desproteger o **VBA**.

Se quiser evitar que o usuário acabe fazendo algo que atrapalhe o envio do `SendKeys` você pode desativar e depois ativar a interação com `Application.Interactive = False` e `Application.Interactive = True`.